# How to listen to an external js event on angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a external js library on my angular app, I added it as a global script on the angular-cli.json scripts array. Its working fine, but I need to assign some functions as response to events of this library. This library has an `Display` object which has some events:

```
Display.onplay
Display.onpause
```

How can I listen to these events in my angular component.ts ?

In plain JavaScript web application is just assign it to a function like:

```
  Display.onplay = function () { console.log('play'); }
```

But on angular I have no idea if its possible to do it.

Comment: It should work, but make sure to define the callback as an arrow function, to avoid [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1009922) with `this` inside the callback.

Comment: but how can I assign it outside of a method? I will get some compilation errors if I type just like that in typescript.

Comment: Maybe you can use `declare var Display: any;` in one of the class files (e.g. the app component, or a service), and assign the callback in the class constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible and appropriate to access external Javascript libraries from an Angular application. There are some issues to keep in mind however.

#### Type Declarations

> I will get some compilation errors if I type just like that in typescript.

This is common in Typescript. There are a couple of ways to fix this issue.

The first (and likely best) approach is to include a Typescript type declaration (.d.ts) file for the `Display` library in your project. If this is a popular third-party library it may already be available as an npm package called @types/[PACKAGE_NAME]. If it is not available you can write a type declaration. More information about creating and including type declarations can be found in the [Typescript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html).

The second approach is to simply use `(Display as any).onplay` or `(Display as any).onpause` to avoid compilation errors.

#### Unit Testing

Placing this code in your top-level component may suffice for your needs, but I doubt it. This restricts where the `Display` library can be used.

I suggest wrapping the library in a well designed service. Using a service allows the `Display` library to be accessed by multiple components/services.

You may be unit testing the code that relies on the `Display` library. If this is the case the appropriate place to use `(Display as any).onplay = ...` would definitely be in a service. Services make it easier to stub the functionality of the third-party libraries.

Here's an untested example service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export interface IDisplayService {
    onPlay(callback: () => void): void;
    onPause(callback: () => void): void;
}

@Injectable()
export class DisplayService implements IDisplayService {
    private onPlayCallback: () => void;
    private onPauseCallback: () => void;

    constructor() {
        if (!Display) {
            throw new Error('Display library is required');
        }

        (Display as any).onplay = () => {
            if (this.onPlayCallback) { this.onPlayCallback(); }
        };
        (Display as any).onpause = () => {
            if (this.onPauseCallback) { this.onPauseCallback(); }
        };
    }

    // Using a function allows you to register multiple callbacks
    // if you choose to allow it later on.
    onPlay(callback: () => void): void {
        this.onPlayCallback = callback;
    }

    onPause(callback: () => void): void {
        this.onPauseCallback = callback;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another aproach using a service and observable of the service an code in your app.component

app.component

```
declare var Display:any //<--declare the variable
@component(..)

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private outEventService:OutEventService) {
  }
  Display.onplay (){   //the function like javascript only call function of service
     this.outEventService.sendEvent("play");
  }
  Display.onpause (){
     this.outEventService.sendEvent("pause");
  }
}
```

outEventService

```
export class OutEventService{

    private listeningSource:Subject<any>=new Subject<any>();
    displayEvent:Observable<any>=this.listeningSource.asObservable();

    constructor() {
    }

    sendEvent(evento:any)  //Simply make a change in the observable
    {
        this.listeningSource.next(evento);
    }
}
```

A component that subscribe event

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone,
    private outEventService: outEventService) {
  }
ngOnInit() {
this.outEventService.displayEvent.subscribe((evento: any) => {
      if (evento == "pause") {  
           do something
      }
      if (evento == "other") {  //Sometimes you must use ngZone to angular take account the change
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            do something 
        })
      }
    });
```